# Can we convert an Android app to ios app completely

Tags: ios

Can we convert an existing android app to Ios App completely  ?. 
will that be accepted by App Store ?

Comment: Are you sure that this is your question?

Comment: yes i want to make sure that is there any converter to convert android app to ios app completely.

Comment: do you have their platform and API knowledge?

Comment: see this http://www.evolutionate.com/convert-your-iphone-app-to-android/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605249/converting-iphone-ipad-apps-onto-android

Comment: yes, there is a converter. It's called a programmer that has intimate knowledge of how your app works, and how to code in ios. Get him to spend a couple weeks doing all the necessary coding and testing. Add time to balance complexity.

Comment: Beware of the license costs of those converters. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such way (Practically convenient) to convert an existing application, if you haven't think about it beforehand. The language concepts are too "different"

If you have used a cross platform framework such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript or PhoneGap this is feasible.

Android is usually built with the java like language, on the IPhone you do your coding in ObjectiveC. Obviously these are completely different entities, so you cannot share code and logic between them.

You can look into "generic" solutions like MonoDroid, MonoTouch which share .net style coding, or you can go towards "phonegap" like HTML5 style cross platform solutions.

In order to convert Android apps on iPhones you need an excellent knowledge of the techniques involved in sloting programs from Android based management system to Apple’s OS.While the porting process may not be as smooth or as easy as one might wish it to be, the idea -pretty much remains the same. The whole idea is to extract as much information as possible from the earlier Android based apps and apply innovative techniques to convert those to iPhone compatible ones.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Nishant apna phone number mail kar de bro.